# Redirect Authorize attribute if it fails to another view in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorize-attribute

so I have a question about the `[Authorize]` tag.  I am required a user to have the role of admin to visit a certain view.  It works great and only allows an "admin" to go to it instead of the "user".  But whenever the user visits it gives me this:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /Login.cshtml

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34009
```

So my question is, when a user visits how can I redirect them to another view?

So this is my controller for index:

```
[Authorize(Users = "Admin")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var user = db.User.Include(u => u.UserRole);
            return View(user.ToList());
        }
```

Comment: It would appear that you do not have a login view, in the web.config defines what page to load when the user is unauthorized, default is login.cshtml.

Comment: So I do have a login view (that is Login.cshtml, made from the User controller), is it the default in the autentication tag in web.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this in two ways:

1. Let the index action be accessible by anonymous user and based on the role call different functions.
2. Create your own custom Authorization attribute (you can find an example [here](http://dotnetdevdude.com/Blog/CommentView,guid,5c9a7035-5652-44fb-99f7-ebbc09cd9d2b.aspx)).

Both the approaches are fine, with no distinct advantage/disadvantage over one and another, so you could choose any of them.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So the authorization class in the example is created under models?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can create it anywhere, just link it to your module. e.g. using ApplicationXYZ.AuthorizationNameSpace.AuthClass;

Comment: Awesome so I am a little closer.  Now when the user tries to access the page. The url is redirected to "http://localhost:62839/Shared/Unauthorized", the only problem is that same error is showing up that I posted in the main question.  ( Unauthrized.cshtml is located in my Shared folder)

Comment: Can you once try to access this page directly. If you are not able to access that as well that means there is some issue with your routing.

Comment: How are you redirecting to Unauthorize.cshtml page, does it allow anonymous access?

Comment: Alright guys so I fixed it.  I did use that class you gave me in the example and called the customAuthorization in my UserController.  Forgot to add the view for Unauthorized.cshtml in the controller ;).  After I did that it all worked glorious.  Marked you as the answer sir and thank you.